# react clearinterval not working for another function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i am working on one of the react project, for that i have used `setInterval` and `clearInterval`, it works fine in same function, but when i used `clearInterval` in another function it is not working, can anyone please help me why it is happening like that ? here i have attached my whole code, can anyone please look my code and help me to resolve this issue ? `clearInterval` is not working for the `onClickStartRound` in  function

```
export class GamePlayBlack extends React.Component<Props, State>
{
    public interval_counter;
    public setTimer = '30:00';
    public setSeconds = 30;
    constructor(props: Props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            gameData: GameDataStore.state,
            userData: UserDataStore.state,
            buttonLoading: false,
            gameStarted: false,
            updateTimer: this.setTimer,
            clearintervaltimer : '',
        };
        localStorage.setItem('is_called','0');
        localStorage.setItem('is_called_show_winner_card','0');
    }


    public componentDidMount(): void
    {
        GameDataStore.listen(data => this.setState({
            gameData: data
        }));

        UserDataStore.listen(data => this.setState({
            userData: data
        }));
    }

    private onSelect = (winningPlayerGuid: string) =>
    {
        return GameDataStore.chooseWinner(this.state.userData.playerGuid, winningPlayerGuid);
    };

    private onClickStartRound = () =>
    {
        localStorage.setItem('is_started','1');
        clearInterval(this.interval_counter);
        
        this.setState({
            buttonLoading: true,
            gameStarted: true,
        });

        GameDataStore.startRound(this.state.userData.playerGuid)
            .finally(() => this.setState({
                buttonLoading: false,
                gameStarted: true,
            }));
    };

    private onClickSkipBlack = () =>
    {
        this.setState({
            buttonLoading: true
        });

        GameDataStore.skipBlack(this.state.userData.playerGuid)
            .finally(() => this.setState({
                buttonLoading: false
            }));
    };

    private waitforstart = (game_id:any,playerGUID:any,chooserGuid:any)  => { //game_id:any,playerGUID:any,chooserGuid:any
        console.log("guid");
        console.log(this.state.gameData);
        console.log(this.state.userData);
        let self = this;
        window.setInterval(function() {
            //alert("sdsd");
            return GameDataStore.removePlayer(game_id,playerGUID,chooserGuid);
        }.bind(self),30000);
    };  

    private skipPlayer = (game_string_id:any,target_turn:any,chooserGuid:any) => {
        return GameDataStore.skipPlayer(game_string_id,target_turn,chooserGuid);
    }

    public startTimer = () => { 
        localStorage.setItem('is_called','1');
        let timer =  this.setSeconds, minutes, seconds;
        let _self = this;  

        this.interval_counter = setInterval(function () {

            let is_started = localStorage.getItem('is_started');
            if(is_started == "0") {
                let chooserGuid = localStorage.getItem('chooserGuid');
                let game_string_id = localStorage.getItem('game_id');
                let target_turn = localStorage.getItem('target_turn');
                let is_called = localStorage.getItem('is_called');

                if(typeof timer!==undefined && timer!=null) {
                    minutes = parseInt(timer/60 as any,10);
                    seconds = parseInt(timer%60 as any,10);
                    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
                    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
                    
                    console.log(minutes + ":" + seconds);
                    
                    _self.setState({
                        updateTimer: minutes + ":" + seconds
                    });
                    
                    if (--timer < 0) {
                        //localStorage.setItem('is_called','0');
                        if(is_started == "0") {
                            _self.skipPlayer(game_string_id,target_turn,chooserGuid);
                                clearInterval(_self.interval_counter);
                            return false;
                        }
                    } 
                }
            }
            
        }, 1000);
    }

    public render()
    {
        const {
            gameData,
            buttonLoading
        } = this.state;
        

        const me = gameData.game?.players?.[this.state.userData.playerGuid];

        const defsLoaded = cardDefsLoaded(gameData);

        if (!me || !gameData.game || !defsLoaded)
        {
            return <ContainerProgress />;
        } else {
            let game_id = gameData.game.id;
            let chooserGuid = gameData.game.chooserGuid;
            let all_players = gameData.game.players;
            let all_player_id = Object.keys(all_players);

            //alert(gameData.game.chooserGuid);

            let filteredAry = all_player_id.filter(e => e !== this.state.userData.playerGuid);

            console.log("guid:"+chooserGuid);   
            console.log("all players:"+all_player_id);  
            console.log("new array:"+filteredAry);

            let target_item = filteredAry.find((_, i, ar) => Math.random() < 1 / (ar.length - i));
            if(typeof target_item !== undefined && target_item!=null) {
                localStorage.setItem('target_turn',target_item);
            }
        }

        const {
            players,
            chooserGuid,
            roundCards,
            roundStarted,
        } = gameData.game;

        const roundCardKeys = Object.keys(roundCards ?? {});

        const remainingPlayerGuids = Object.keys(players ?? {})
            .filter(pg => !(pg in (roundCards ?? {})) && pg !== chooserGuid);

        const remainingPlayers = remainingPlayerGuids.map(pg => unescape(players?.[pg]?.nickname));

        const revealedIndex = this.state.gameData.game?.revealIndex ?? 0;
        const timeToPick = remainingPlayers.length === 0;
        const revealMode = timeToPick && revealedIndex < roundCardKeys.length;
        const hasWinner = !!gameData.game?.lastWinner;

        if(!roundStarted) {
            //alert(chooserGuid);
            localStorage.setItem('is_started','0');
            if(typeof gameData.game.id !== undefined && gameData.game.id!=null) {
                localStorage.setItem('game_id',gameData.game.id);
            }
            if(typeof gameData.game.chooserGuid !== undefined && gameData.game.chooserGuid!=null) {
                localStorage.setItem('chooserGuid',gameData.game.chooserGuid);
            }           
            let is_called = localStorage.getItem('is_called');
            if(is_called == "0") {
                this.startTimer();      
            }
        } else { 
            localStorage.setItem('is_started','1');
        }

        return (
            <>
                <div>
                    <PlayersRemaining/>
                </div>
                <Divider style={{margin: "1rem 0"}}/>

                {!roundStarted && (
                    <Typography style={{marginBottom: "1rem", textAlign: "center"}}>
                        <strong>You are the Card Captain!</strong>
                        <br/>
                        Read the card aloud, then click Start The Round. Once everyone plays, you will choose your favorite!<br/>
                        <span> {this.state.updateTimer}</span> Seconds
                    </Typography>
                )}

                {!timeToPick && roundStarted && (
                    <CardPlayTimeRemaining gameData={gameData}/>
                )}
                <Grid container spacing={2} style={{justifyContent: "center", marginTop: "1rem"}}>
                    {(!hasWinner) && (
                        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
                            <BlackCard packId={gameData.game?.blackCard.packId}>
                                {gameData.blackCardDef?.content}
                            </BlackCard>
                        </Grid>
                    )}
                    <RevealWhites canReveal={true}/>
                    <ShowWinner/>
                </Grid>
                {!roundStarted && (
                    <div style={{marginTop: "1rem", textAlign: "center"}}>
                        <LoadingButton loading={buttonLoading} color={"secondary"} variant={"outlined"} onClick={this.onClickSkipBlack}>
                            Skip Card
                        </LoadingButton>
                        <LoadingButton loading={buttonLoading} color={"secondary"} variant={"contained"} onClick={this.onClickStartRound} style={{marginLeft: "1rem"}}>
                            Start the round!
                        </LoadingButton>
                    </div>
                )}
                <PickWinner
                    canPick={true}
                    hasWinner={hasWinner}
                    onPickWinner={this.onSelect}
                    revealMode={revealMode}
                    timeToPick={timeToPick}
                />
            </>
        );
    }
}
```